# Django change foreign key data and save

Tags: django, orm, foreign-key-relationship, many-to-one

I have two models like

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Now for an object of Article lets say

```
a=Article.objects.filter(id=1)
a=a[0]
```

I try to change the headline and the email of the author who has written this article so I do

```
a.heagline = "Saving foreign key does not work"
a.reporter.email = "changed@email.com"
a.save()
```

This saves the Article object but does not modify the Reporter.

I explicitly have to do

```
a.reporter.save()
```

to see the changes to the reporter object. As this is a Many to One relation it should also modify the Foreign key on saving

How can I save the parent Model too by just calling the childs save method

Comment: How can I save the parent Model too by just calling the childs save method

Comment: There is no direct way but you can always override the `save` method of your child model.

Comment: You can probably override the save method of the child to do this but thats wasteful and will probably cause you issues at some point. *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: Why would you be able to do this? If you are modifying linked object you should perform `save` on that object - modifying "from backstage" seems to be very *very* bad idea and in the future you can have problems with finding out why your object is being modified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could override the save method or just create a custom method.

```
class Article(models.Model):

    ...

    # Overriding save
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.reporter.save()
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    # Creating a custom method 
    def save_related(self):
        self.reporter.save()
        self.save()
```

I suggest you create a custom method because it doesn't introduce unexpected behavior in `save()`

Comment: Yes but this has just created extra work for something that is most likely only needed for a couple of certain use cases.

Comment: @Sayse totally agree, that is why I presented both approaches.

Comment: I just can't see what the actual problem is, doing this buys you nothing over one extra line of code that works for everyone else

Comment: @Sayse IMHO, just because doing something might be bad idea doesn't mean we shouldn't answer the original question. The concerns have been raised in the comments, it is up to the asker to come to their own conclusion.

Comment: True, but from experience, this just leads to future questions where the OP's then have to add a hack above another hack just to achieve functionality that was available in the first place. This can more often than not be resolved by spending the extra 5 minutes just figuring out what they are actually asking about ([XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))