# Edit foreign key value in Django admin

Tags: django

I have model an Django model as follows:

```
class BusinessUnit(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    address = models.ForeignKey(to=Address)
    vat_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

How can I change `address` directly from `BusinessUnit` in Django admin?

Now I can only select the address, but I cant change it. I need to go to `Address` model and change it there, but I want to be able to change it directly in `BusinessUnit` model.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422174/django-change-foreign-key-data-and-save